# aliasing proper type as existential type (why it compiles?)

Tags: scala

Why can I do the following:

```
class A
type M[_] = A
```

I would expect I can only alias type that expects one type parameter, for example a `List[_]`, but it works also with plain classes.

If I create a method:

```
def foo(m: M[_]) = m
```

and call it with wrong parameter:

```
scala> foo("a")
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("a")
 required: M[_]
    (which expands to)  A[]
       foo("a")
```

I get such error. What is the meaning of `A[]`?

Going further, how to explain this:

```
scala> type M[_, _] = A
<console>:12: error: _ is already defined as type _
       type M[_, _] = A
```

Is there a way to assure that what I put on the right hand side of my alias will be a parametrized type?

Comment: To your 2nd question: is `class A[T <: AnyRef,U <: AnyVal] `  & `type M = A[_,_]`   what you want?

Comment: @Samar This is a very different situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type M[_] = A` is the same as `type M[X] = A`: a constant function on types. `M[X]` is `A` whatever `X` is: `M[Int]` is `A`, `M[String]` is `A`, `M[Any]` is `A`, etc. `_` in this case is just an identifier (which explains the error for `type M[_, _]` as well).

Of course, in `def foo(m: M[_]) = m`, `M[_]` is an existential type: `M[T] forSome { type T }`. I don't know why Scala says it expands to `A[]` in the error message, though; this may be a bug. You can check it's the same type as `A` by calling

```
scala> implicitly[M[_] =:= A]
res0: =:=[A[],A] = <function1>
```

> Is there a way to assure that what I put on the right hand side of my alias will be a parametrized type?

You can declare an abstract member type with higher-kind

```
trait Foo { type M[_] }
```

and it can only be implemented by parametrized types:

```
class Bar1 extends Foo { type M = Int } // fails
class Bar2 extends Foo { type M[X] = List[X] } // works
```

Of course, as mentioned in the first paragraph, `M` in `type M[X] = Int` *is* parametrized, and I don't think there is a way to rule it out.

Comment: is there a university dedicated to understanding scala type system? how can i join it?